# Changing volume of one AudioSource in an array with a slider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am trying to control the volume of the first audiosource in an array with a slider. The problem is that it's telling me there is no definition for 'volume' in audiosources[0].volume. The script is in an AudioManager from a tutorial from Brackeys: [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OT43pvUyfY).

```
//Volumeslider
    public void VolumeSlider(float newVolume)
    {
        Component[] audiosources;
        audiosources = GetComponents(typeof(AudioSource));
        audiosources[0].volume = newVolume;
```

The error: 'Component' does not contain a definition for 'volume' and no accessible extension method 'volume' accepting a first argument of type 'Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS1061)

This is my first question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you have correctly retrieved all the AudioSource components with `GetComponents`, since the type of the array is `Component[]`, that means each individual element of the array is of type `Component`.

`Component` does not have a definition for volume. Think of something like `Animator` or `MeshFilter`. Those are also subclasses of `Component`, so they could be assigned to elements in your array. What would happen if you tried to access *their* `volume` properties?

What you should do instead is, be as specific as possible - that is the whole point of a strongly typed language like C#. You could do this:

```
var audioSources = GetComponents<AudioSource>();
audioSources[0].volume = newVolume;
```

The major difference is using the "generic" version of `GetComponents` (the one with < angle brackets >. The reason is then, you actually get an array, `AudioSource[]` of the correct type, instead of the basic `Component` type, which A) doesn't have the field you want, and B) needs to be cast to AudioSource before you can use it how you want.

Other improvements I made: camelCase for variable names, inferred variable type (`var`, so you only have to change it in one place if you need to use another kind of component later. If you mouse over the `var` it will tell you that the type is actually `AudioSource[]`), assignment on the same line as declaration (less clutter.)

Comment: Thank you, your explanation really helped me understand it better but now I've got an error when I change the slider saying: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I don't know how this is possible because the both the volume of the audioSource[0] and my slider start at 0.2 and the error comes up if I change it even the slightest.

Comment: That means that the index (0) didn't exist in the array. If an array doesn't have an element at 0, that means it's empty. Which means that your `GetComponents` call returned no AudioSource components. Which means that you have to check whether you actually have any on the object. You can do that at runtime with an `if` statement, but you should also probably just look at the game object in the inspector and make sure it's set up as you expect.

Comment: @joseph,
In the documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html) example:

        Component[] hingeJoints;

        hingeJoints = GetComponents(typeof(HingeJoint));

        foreach (HingeJoint joint in hingeJoints)
            joint.useSpring = false;

Comment: You said:
Even though you have correctly retrieved all the AudioSource components with GetComponents, since the type of the array is Component[], that means each individual element of the array is of type Component.
Component does not have a definition for volume. Think of something like Animator or MeshFilter. Those are also subclasses of Component, so they could be assigned to elements in your array. What would happen if you tried to access their volume properties?

Comment: Here's my doubt:
In the documentation example, they iterated the array using a foreach loop and accessed the array elements as HingeJoint and disabling the spring property of the HingeJoint.

I am a newbie so I am confused. Could you clear my doubt, please?

Comment: The trick in that document is the `foreach`, which casts the object. If you don't use the foreach, you would have to do the cast manually, like `(HingeJoint)component[0]`. That cast can fail and you can get an exception. They get away with it because they gather the components just before and they're assured of the type.